# Add default type affect how TS infer the generic

Tags: typescript

Here is the playground that describe the question.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcDqMoAsAiBTYAQxABsoAVATwAc8AeAKEUXIFlDrE8APKPMACYBnRACU8EOACcBdIVCkwwAcwA0iABQBvRGEIBbPIgC+ALkQ69h8-MUqTASkQBeAHyJCYSu+cXjDVw0IQhISACNCCABrdmpzNg4nLSZEAHpUxAE4RCE4Q2wlZQZ-BlBIWARkVAxsOBAofCJSChp6FITOHj5BEXFJGTkFQvVtXQMjMwsx6xyh+2MnNw8vdwCgkPDImI542KSU9Mzs3PysQuKGUurMXAJiMipabRTCcw1qQikDRfctY1UDhklMA8FIpHgBB4RJ5KMUHABuS4odA3OoNO7NR54Z7MV6aD5ffQ-PwA5iHRDA0HgyH9cHQEiURBw+FAA)

```
function fooWithDefaultType<
  TMap extends Record<string, ({ name }: { name: string }) => any> = {}
>(callbackMap: TMap) {
  // do something
}

function fooWithoutDefaultType<
  TMap extends Record<string, ({ name }: { name: string }) => any> 
>(callbackMap: TMap) {
  // do something
}

fooWithDefaultType({
  a: (param) => {},
  // inferred as any
});

fooWithoutDefaultType({
  a: (param) => {},
  //  inferred correctly 
});
```

After adding the default type, the TS lost its ability to infer the param type correctly. Anyone can explain? Thanks!

Comment: Default type should really be the same as the constraint : https://tsplay.dev/Nr8AoW

Answer (score 0):

if you have default type and you do not assign another type

then the type is the default type
[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcDqMoAsAiBTYAQxABsoAVATwAc8AeAKEUXIFlDrE8APKPMACYBnRACU8EOACcBdIVCkwwAcwA0iABQBvRGEIBbPIgC+ALkQ69h8-MUqTASkQBeAHyJCYSu+cXjDVw0IQhISACNCCABrdmpzNg4uXn5hXTwANzwpRAB+FljEeNinLQZ-BgB6CsRsIygaIxgRLWMPQUR9OHkahpEePkFm1srqgHcsGAgsRCbEccoarDqGxDhgRGpCKQNEYLAwOChEMKMBPD59JTwBNpvRmFDjiThDRAADT0o3ntoGFHRMLgCMQyFRaNomB5zBpNtt9E43BYTKpIVVEAA9HJlBwAbgYI0QQgMRmCQiMhCEDEkYG6fG6vg06XMLQR7h0-jpUAhzEI0NhBlZSOMKOYaMx2LxI2c0plstlQjgJBAsAQcrVznxaIpQhgyiQyn4WUmPzwBNqJpmInEkhkcgUSjUmksxJMzN0xJs9vsxkFn1cf1QGGw+CIpAoDTo1ukslsDvU2ndrzMSKseE9dmUjhc7j9gVKPL5WwF2aFIsQYqxPslWqEOr1JoDAODwLDYLw3Khmn5+jdqfTDqziPZZbRzDH4+Y4qrDCAA)

in your case, the default type is pointless because it is
"wider"(well actually they can extends each other) than the constraint, I recommend you drop the default type

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)